# iTunes Connect Testflight Internal Tester Latest Build Status Version Entry Wrong / Inaccurate

Tags: ios, iphone, testing, app-store-connect, testflight

I have set up some internal testers on our iTunes Connect Testflight. I am finding that the entries for their 'Latest Build' which tells me the current version each tester has installed is completely unreliable. I know for a fact that some of my testers have installed the absolute latest build, but the iTunes Connect console is telling me that they only have an older build installed.

This of course makes the whole premise of 'Latest Build' completely useless. As dev, I need to remotely, immediately & reliably know if when the tester is experiencing a bug, which version they have installed. This seems to me to be a rather serious iTunes Testflight bug. It's actually causing me more headache than good.

[image]

Is anyone else finding this annoying issue plaguing them? Does anyone know what triggers a tester's installed build version to actually get registered? Then at least I could get all of my testers to install in that way when they update, i.e to make sure they click through the update email for example, if that's what's required..

Comment: I just noticed this with some of my testers today. Have you tried contacting Apple yet?

Comment: Admittedly, I didn't get around to it. Let me know if you do!

Comment: I called customer support and am filling a report with screenshots and info for them to research further. I encourage you to call as well to help bump this bug's priority :)

`iTC Support) USA/Canada: +1 (800) 633-2152  Other: +1 (408) 974-4897`